# Ionic 5 app unresponsive or freeze when maximize or notification drawer open in android

Tags: freeze, ionic5

Getting strange issue for **ionic 5** app,
Application works fine till it is in foreground.
Once application minimize and again maximize it is unresponsive , freeze on scroll , page routing are slow.
I have checked in logcat logs , it **shows Skip 100 frames, Main thread doing too much work**.
but app is just come back to foreground nothing changed.
also shows **error activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed /mainactivity**.

I am using **ionic 5.4.16**

Hope someone answer it,

Forget to mention , i have implemented AWS App SYnc, is that is reason of main thread doing lots of work when app resume.

Comment: Try to search if you're using lots of ionViewDidLoad, ionViewWillEnter code. These gets triggered when app resume.

Comment: I checked that also , all init things done in ngOnInit(), in ionViewDidLoad only checked flags